# Get values of a document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using cloud firestore. There I store array's in documents. Here is a screenshot:
[image]
 I get the documents like this:

```
db.collection("users").doc(user_uid).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());

          addToTable(doc.id, doc.mdl, doc.klu);
      });
    });
```

But my Problem is that it says that the values of doc.mdl and doc.klu are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The properties of the document are in the properties of the object returned by `doc.data()`.  They are not properties of the `doc`, which is a [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) type object:

```
const data = doc.data()
console.log(doc.id, data.mdl, data.klu)
```

Comment: Thank you. One last question. Is there a way to put a ',' between the values of the array?

Comment: That's a different question that's not really related to the first.  Try searching for the JavaScript solution that works best for your needs, or ask a whole new question describing your new problem. I suspect you may want to learn how to "join" elements of an array.